# Initializing viewmodel with data in knockout

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I am trying to set my view model with below initial data.

```
var initialVMData = [{"title":"Mrs","otherTitle":null,"forename":"Tom","surname":"Sam"},{"title":"Miss","otherTitle":null,"forename":"Sarah","surname":"Miller"}]
```

Here is my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/asad23/p8VCQ/):

I am struggling to initialize my view model so that on first page load there are two records already populated with the in above JSON (initialVMData). I have tried using mapping plugin but no success yet. What is the simplest way to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: If you have tried with the mapping plugin, can you show us a jsFiddle of that? If you have it somewhere saved ofcourse.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my jsFiddle with knockout mapping.

Comment: Why downvote? Can someone please explain the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one.
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p8VCQ/10/)

First you need to provide an option to initialize your `JointHolder` objects with some data.
Then you need to map your `jointholders` array with JSON data. I've used `$.map` function for that.
And that's it.